# How to read a variable from file, modify and safe it to an other variale

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, sed

### What I want:

There is a file `/scripts/backup/config.cfg` which contains variables. In my specific case the important ones are:

```
BACKUPLOCATION=""
ROOTLOCATION="/backup"
```

Then there is a script `/scripts/backup/performBackup.sh`
For a specific reason I want a part of the script do the following operations:

1. read the value of the variable `ROOTLOCATION`
2. add a ("/" and) timestamp (Date&Time)
3. safe the new created value to `BACKUPLOCATION` (by replacing its current value)

#### Example

If this is the previous state of the `config.cfg`:

```
BACKUPLOCATION="dummy"
ROOTLOCATION="/backup"
```

After the script ran it should be:

```
BACKUPLOCATION="/backup/2020-05-02-23-00"
ROOTLOCATION="/backup/"
```

#### What I tried

First of all the config file gets "loaded" using

```
source /scripts/backup/config.cfg
```

I then tried to use the `sed` command but the quotes are messing with me. Here is one try (which didn't work):

```
sed -i 's/BACKUPLOCATION\=.*/BACKUPLOCATION="'$ROOTLOCATION/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)'"/' /scripts/backup/config.cfg
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include "Hello" or similar. See here for more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: you have chosen `/` as the delimiter for sed replacement, but your strings contain unescaped `/`. Chose something else, like a comma: `sed -i 's,BACKUPLOCATION\=.*,BACKUP...`

Comment: Please look at the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com); There's no need to tell us about your intended read-edit-write if the only problem is in the editing.

Comment: @Beta because I didn't now the exact root of the problem I tought I better explain a little background if the general approach was wrong. But I keep that in mind for the future. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
source /scripts/backup/config.cfg
sed -i 's|BACKUPLOCATION=.*|BACKUPLOCATION="'"$ROOTLOCATION/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)"'"|' /scripts/backup/config.cfg
```

The problem with your sed is that you use `/` as delimiter, which is present in `$ROOTLOCATION` after expansion, therefore sed fails. I used `|`, which is usually is not present in filenames. If you ever create a file with `|`, that sed will fail too! So, "know your data" :)

Comment: @Techflix You made a pretty good job for a beginner, but some subtleties sometimes arise.